# Low level languages and their dependencies

Tags: c, compilation, low-level

I am trying to understand exactly what it means that low-level languages are machine-dependent.

Let's take for example C, well if it is machine-dependent does it mean that if it was compiled on one computer it might not be able to run on another?

Comment: The statement _"low-level languages are machine-dependent."_ is pretty meaningless.

Comment: What context did you find it in?  Was it maybe talking about how `sizeof(void*)` is different on 32-bit vs. 64-bit builds, or even on 16-bit microcontrollers?  Also in theory `CHAR_BIT` if you include old and rare machines, along with many other type-width and other differences, like FLT_EVAL_METHOD (e.g. x87 80-bit temporaries vs. rounding to `double` after every step).  Unlike Java where `int` is always 32-bit 2's complement and a bunch of other things are also nailed down about the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end processors executes machine code which is basicly a collection of binary numbers. The processor decode each binary number to figure out what it is supposed to do. One binary number could mean "Add register X to register Y and store the result in register Z". Another binary number could mean "Store the content of register X into the memory address held by register Y". And so on...

The complete description of these decoding rules (i.e. binary number into operation) represents the processors instruction set (aka ISA).

A low level language is a language where the code you can write maps very closely to the specific processors instruction set. Assembly is one obvious example. Since different processor may have different instruction sets, it's clear that an assembly program written for one processors ISA can't be used on a processor with a different ISA.

> Let's take for example C, well if it is machine-dependent does it mean that if it was compiled on one computer it might not be able to run on another?

Correct. A program compiled for one processor (family) can't run on another processor with (completely) different ISA. The program needs to be recompiled.

Also notice that the target OS also plays a role. If you use the same processor but use different OS you'll also need to recompile.

There are at least 3 different kind of languages.

1. A languages that is so close to the target systems ISA that the source code can only be used on that specific target. Example: Assembly
2. A language that allows you to write code that can be used on many different targets using a target specific compilation. Example: C
3. A language that allows you to write code that can be used on many different targets without a target specific compilation. These still require some kind of target specific runtime environment to be installed. Example: Java.

Answer (score 0):

High-Level languages are portable, meaning every architecture can run high-level programs but, compared to low-level programs (like written in `Assembly` or even machine code), they are less efficient and consume more memory.

Low-level programs are known as "closer to the hardware" and so they are optimized for a certain type of hardware architecture/processor, being faster programs, but relatively machine-dependant or not-very-portable.
So, a program compiled for a type of processor it's not valid for other types; it needs to be recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

## In the before

When the first processors came out, there was no programming language whatsoever, you had a very long and very complicated documentation with a list of "opcodes": the code you had to put into memory for a given operation to be executed in your processor. To create a program, you had to put a long string of number in memory, and hope everything worked as documented.

Later came Assembly languages. The point wasn't really to make algorithms easier to implement or to make the program readable by any human without any experience on the specific processor model you were working with, it was created to save you from spending days and days looking up things in a documentation. For this reason, there isn't "an assembly language" but thousands of them, one per instruction set (which, at the time, basically meant one per CPU model)

At this point in time, all languages were platform-dependent. If you decided to switch CPUs, you'd have to rewrite a significant portion (if not all) of your code. Recognizing that as a bit of a problem, someone created a the first platform-independent language (according to [this SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/1640329/which-was-the-first-platform-independent-programming-language) it was FORTRAN in 1954) that could be compiled to run on any CPU architecture as long as someone made a compiler for it.

Fast forward a bit and C was invented. C is a platform-independent programming language, in the sense that any C program (as long as it conforms with the standard) can be compiled to run on any CPU (as long as this CPU has a C compiler). Once a C program has been compiled, the resulting file is a platform-dependent binary and will only be able to run on the architecture it was compiled for.

## C is platform-dependent

There's an issue though: a processor is more than just a list of opcodes. Most processors have hardware control devices like watchdogs or timers that can be completely different from one architecture to another, even the way to talk to other devices can change completely. As such, if you want to actually run a program on a CPU, you have to include things that make it platform-dependent.

A real life example of this is the Linux kernel. The majority of the kernel is written in C but there's still around 1% written in different kinds of assembly. This assembly is required to do things such as initialize the CPU or use timers. Using this hack means Linux can run on your desktop x86_64 CPU, your ARM Android phone or a RISCV SoC but adding any new architecture isn't as simple as just "compile it with your architecture's compiler".

So... Did I just say the only way to run a platform-independent on an actual processor is to use platform-dependent code? Yes, for most architectures, you have to.

## Or is it?

But there's a catch! That's only true if you want to run you code on bare metal (meaning: without an OS). One of the great things of using an OS is how abstracted everything is: you don't need to know how the kernel initializes the CPU, nor do you need to know how it gets its clock, you just need to know how to access those abstracted resources.

But the way of accessing resources dependent on the OS, aren't we back to square one? We could be, if not for the standard library! This library is used to access functions like `printf` in a defined way. It doesn't matter if you're working on a Linux running on PowerPC or on an ARM Windows, printf will always print things on the standard output the same way.

If you write standard C using only the standard library (and intend for your program to run in an OS) **C is completely platform-independent**!

EDIT: As said in the comments below, even that is not enough. It doesn't really have anything to do with specific CPUs but some things such as the `system` function or the size of some types are documented as implementation-defined. To make C really platform independent you need to make sure to only use well defined functions of the STL and learn some best practice (never rely on `sizeof(int)==4` for instance).

Comment: The last sentence is false. Using only standard library routines in a conforming C program for a hosted implementation is insufficient to guarantee platform independence. There remain numerous unspecified, implementation-defined, and undefined behaviors in C.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", (int)sizeof(void*));` will print different outputs on different machines (C implementations), as an example of what @EricPostpischil was talking about.  It's easy to write code that is *accidentally* dependent on things like that, rather than intentionally like this was.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about 'what's a program' might help you understand your question. Is a program a collection of text (that you've typed in or otherwise manufactured) or is it something you run? Is it both?

In the case of a 'low-level' language like C I'd say that the text is the program source, and that this is turned into a program (aka executable) by a compiler. A program is something you can run. You need a C compiler for a system to be able to make the program source into a program for that system. Once built the program can only be run on systems close to the one it was compiled for. However there is a more interesting, if more difficult question: can you at least keep the program source the same, so that all you need to do is recompile? The answer to this is 'sort-of No' I sort-of think. For example you can't, in pure C, read the state of the shift key. Of course operating systems provide such facilities and you can interface to those in C, but then such code depends on the OS. There might be libraries (eg the curses library) that provide such facilities for many OS and that can help to reduce the dependency, but no library can clain to portably cover all OS.

In the case of a 'higher-level' language like python I'd say the text is both the program and the program source. There is no separate compilation stage with such languages, but you do need an interpreter on a system to be able to run your python program on that system. However that this is happening may not be clear to the user as you may well seem to be able to run your python 'program' just by naming it like you run your C programs. But this, most likely comes down to the shell (the part of the OS that deals with commands) knowing about python programs and invoking the interpreter for you. It can appear then that you can run your python program anywhere but in fact what you can do is pass the program to any python interpreter.

In the zoo of programming there are not only many, very varied beasts, but new kinds of beasts arise all the time, and old beasts metamorphose. Terms like 'program', 'script' and even 'executable' are often used loosely.